# md raid and partitions on large disks

Tags: linux, raid, partition, lvm

Has anyone else seen problems using linux software raid on large (2TB) disks with guid partition tables? We have a CentOS box that loses it during boot, and requires the raid be reassembled. Unfortunately, it's the only box I have with a bunch of 2TB disks, and it needs to go into production.

I would prefer to have a partition table on the disk, to ensure that the block devices are identical in size, especially if drives need to be replaced. Am I being too cautious, and I should simply build the array with the raw devices?

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't recommend using the raw devices, that caused auto-detection issues for us which were fixed by creating one large partition on each drive and building an array using those.

Answer (score 0):

Try using adding the rootdelay option to your boot arguments. You'll need to play with the values to see what you need without wasting too much time but 5 should be a good start.

Example on my machine:

```
kernel /xen.gz-2.6.18-128.4.1.el5 rootdelay=5
```

Comment: Does rootdelay effect all filesystems? In my case, / is fine, and on a separate controller entirely.